# NaN is clearly a number, or is it?

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm having a bit of trouble here. I checked to make sure my variable was defined only with numbers, but the code is still returning as not a number. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Code below:

```
//declare vars and/or constants
var endString = "Total cost per night is $";
var viewCost;
var discount;

//input vars
pplCount = prompt("How many people will be staying?");
discYes = prompt("Do you have an AAA discount?");
viewYes = prompt("Do you want a room with a view?");

//if variables

if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 50 * 0.15;
roomCost = 50;
roomCost = +roomCost - discount + viewCost;
viewCost = (+roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 60 * 0.10;
roomCost = 60;
roomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 70 * 0.05;
roomCost = 70;
roomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}

else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 50 * 0.15;
roomCost = 50;
roomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 60 * 0.10;
roomCost = 60;
roomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
discount = 70 * 0.05;
roomCost = 70;
roomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}

else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 50 * 0.15;
roomCost = 50;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 60 * 0.10;
roomCost = 60;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 70 * 0.05;
roomCost = 70;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}

else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 50 * 0.15;
roomCost = 50;
roomCost = roomCost - discount;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 60 * 0.10;
roomCost = 60;
roomCost = roomCost - discount;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
discount = 70 * 0.05;
roomCost = 70;
roomCost = roomCost - discount;
viewCost = (roomCost * 0.10);
document.write(endString + roomCost);
}
```

Is it because I'm defining roomCost twice?

Comment: What is the problem/question? And where in the code is it?

Comment: When I run the program, it works fine, but the endString variable prints out "Total cost per night is $NaN", so that means the roomCost variable is being read as not a number.

Comment: viewCost never seem to be initialized. I guess it is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` is what you get when a `Number` operation gives an invalid result (Not a Number)

Like:

```
5 - "a"
5 + NaN
parseInt("a", 10)
5 + undefined
```

`NaN` is *poisonous* in the sense that any operation that has `NaN` as an operand will return `NaN` as well. Figure out where you bad operation is.

Glancing at you're code, I see that you're operating with strings instead of Numbers. Use `parseInt()` to convert a string into a proper Number. Make sure you validate your input, if `parseInt` returns `NaN` give an error.

Comment: Ah okay! I did some fiddling and moving the final roomCost to a new var and moving viewCost above that seemed to fix it, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the other naughty stuff you're doing here, you're using `viewCost` in a few places without defining it first. (It's *Not A Number*.)

Changing the first few lines to the following fixes the problem:

```
//declare vars and/or constants
var endString = "Total cost per night is $";
var viewCost = 0;
var discount = 0;
```

Comment: `undefined !== NaN`, an operation with `undefined` as an operand will return `NaN` though.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I don't think you can reliably compare to `NaN`. In the Chrome console, `1 + undefined !== NaN` for instance. However, `isNaN(undefined) === true`. They're different, but for the purpose of the answer and all practical applications, they're effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var viewCost; // <---defined, but not assigned to

roomCost = +roomCost - discount + viewCost;
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

at the time you run this the first time, you've only declared the variable, but haven't assigned to it yet: